# Approximate the savings account balance after 12 years using the first four terms of the exponential series

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, trigonometry

She deposited $ {$500}$ in a savings account with a $ 4.5 $ percent interest rate compounded continuously. (The formula for continuously compounded interest is $A=Pe^{rt}$)

I know her savings account balance will be about ${$856.02}$ but how do we get that?

Comment: Do you understand what the variables in your equation $A=Pe^{rt}$ mean?

Answer (score 1):

$A = Pe^{rt}$.  You're given $P = 500$, $r = 0.045$, and $t = 12$.

$A = 500 e^{(0.045)(12)} = 500 e^{0.54}$.

Now use the first four terms of the Taylor series for $e^x$ (shown below), with $x = 0.54$, to evaluate $e^{0.54}$.  Don't forget to multiply by $500$.

$$e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!} = \underbrace{1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!}}_{\text{use these four terms}} + \cdots$$